# Push fir base notification dynamical every device different notification in single API post

Tags: asp.net, firebase, push-notification

I want to push firebase notification dynamically every device different notification in bulk using asp.net

`https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send`

```
[{
 "to" : "eqGiWA3POYA:APA91bHXf-Eo9aUI-XtIdHUcGrWaNtfgjPM3luED2LRAafAvemPIBOoUEXFCjnnoAL5xOXescizfpafi-RqwssuyHclShImoYNzYaAjrrw03rLPMLUjN7pAW3RJj1P3f07VJxGBmGm6z",
 "collapse_key" : "type_a",
 "notification" : {
     "body" : "Body of Your Notification",
     "title": "Title of Your Notification"
 },
 "data" : {
     "body" : "Body of Your Notification in Data",
     "title": "Title of Your Notification in Title",
     "key_1" : "Value for key_1",
     "key_2" : "Value for key_2"
 }

}]
```

it's working on single message multiple device.

I need different message different device based on device registered id.

Comment: Based on my knowledge you cannot send different message for each device as bulk batch.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message) it doesn't seem possible to do what you are trying to do. You would need to send the messages in a loop seperatly.